Constructing generators of normal closure of relators in terms of relators
Say we have a presentation of the trivial group $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \mid r_1,\ldots, r_n\rangle$. Since the group is trivial, the normal closure of the relators is the entire ambient free group, i.e., $\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n \mid\ \rangle$.
This means that we can write any generator $x_i$ as a product of conjugates of the $r_i$, namely, $x_i=w_1 (r_{i_1})^{\pm1}w_1^{-1}w_2 (r_{i_2})^{\pm 1}w_2^{-1}\cdots w_m (r_{i_m})^{\pm 1}w_m^{-1}$, for words $w_i$ in the $x_i$ and $i_k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$.
My question is twofold: is there an explicit algorithm that allows us to construct a generator (or word) as a product of conjugates of the $r_i$ in this way? Second, what can we say about the value of $m$, in particular as a function of the length of the relators?
Any insight along any of these lines is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Are you familiar with the word problem and that it is undecidable? Also, what type of algorithm do you request? There is an obvious algorithm that simply checks all combinations (there are countably many) and it will stop basically because you have assumed that it must stop. But is this what you want?

This is generally believed to be a very difficult problem. I think it is provably more difficult than the word problem itself for groups with solvable word problem

@MartinBrandenburg What is the obvious algorithm? Because we might have to conjugate a relator for an arbitrary word, it is easy for me to design an algorithm that never stops. I guess I can simply enumerate them in an intelligent way, but I also wonder if there's anything better I can do. Thanks for your comment

Yes I meant take an arbitrary enumeration of all possible elements in the normal closure. This enumeration can be defined explicitly (by going through th proof that the set is countable). But I assume this is not a satisfactory answer which is why I ask you to clarify the requirements. The "algorithm" of going through all elements stops because of your assumption that the group is trivial.

@MartinBrandenburg The case in particular I am interested in is the case of a wirtinger presentation of an unknot (a presentation of $\mathbb{Z}$), with one relation added to trivialize the group. I am interested in any algorithm that is more intelligent than an enumeration. Thank you for your responses
